# How can I auto-increment a column without using IDENTITY?

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a table with two columns that I want to auto-increment. One column is a primary key, so I'm using the IDENTITY keyword on it. The other column will be used to track the user-defined "sort order" of items in the table. Any time the user moves an item, its "sort order" will swap values with that of another element. However, when an item is inserted into the table, the inserted item should always be auto-assigned a sort-order value higher than any other value in the table. Here's a simplified version of the table creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE [AnswerRow] (
    [AnswerRowId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SortOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_AnswerRow_IsDeleted] DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AnswerRow] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AnswerRowId] asc)
)
```

What's the best way to make the `SortOrder` column auto-increment the same way the `AnswerRowId` column will (but still be able to modify sort-order values afterward)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what @Stephen Wrighton had in mind, but I think you could have an insert trigger make use of the IDENTITY value being generated for AnswerRowId:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AnswerRowInsertTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[AnswerRow]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE a SET a.SortOrder = a.AnswerRowId
    FROM AnswerRow a JOIN inserted i ON a.AnswerRowId = i.AnswerRowId

END
```

Comment: When I referenced a trigger, that's close, but updating based on the wrong value (he's looking for the next value for the sortorder, not the auto-incremented ID value). Yet, as I stated, a trigger would not be my first choice (it never is) due to what I view as the inherent issues associated with triggers (not least of those that as a coder, I don't inherently think to look at triggers when trying to figure out what a record is doing).

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, Nice answer, plus one addition, also check if SortOrder has null value then update it else don't update it with AnserRowId

Comment: @Stephen Wrighton: Due to the way the identity column works, this strategy should ensure that `SortOrder + 1` is always the same as `AnswerRowId`. I just need to make sure that we're always swapping, rather than setting sort orders to values higher than what's in the table already. @Waqas Raja: SortOrder is not null, so an insert value should always be provided (probably 0), and then overridden by the trigger.

Answer (score 5):

Two ways come to mind right off, the first is a trigger, which is not what I'd do personally.

The second, would be to have my sql do something along these lines:

```
INSERT INTO AnswerRow(SortOrder, IsDeleted, Answer)
SELECT MAX(SortOrder) + 1, 0, 'My New Answer'
FROM AnswerRow
```

Comment: MAX(SortOrder) + 1 will not allways be the same as @@identity

Comment: @karel - He's using a sort order not the identity field so this is ok.

Comment: Because I'm using an ORM rather than writing my SQL code directly, I think this approach isn't ideal, but I appreciate the response.

Comment: If you're using an ORM then make the inserts happen via Stored Procedures. Alternatively, you can get the MAX sortorder immediately prior to insertion from your ORM (i.e. in say linqto sql: (from y in dc.AnswerRows Order By SortOrder Descending SELECT SortOrder).take(1).singleordefault)

Comment: I don't feel that using a stored procedure for my inserts is any easier or more obvious than setting a trigger, and it makes it that much more difficult to guarantee that the SortOrder will always be set. Your second suggestion would involve two round-trips, and require that they be done in a single transaction scope in order to prevent data mismatches. For me, that's a bit too much overhead just to avoid a trigger. Thanks again, though.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I've found it much easier to use a floating-point column for my sort position than to use an integer value. For new records, you would still need a trigger that sets the value equal to the largest existing value plus some constant (say 100). For updating the sort position of an item, though, you can simply find the sort position of the entry before and the entry after the entry you are moving. Average those two values and you have your new sort position.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Something inside me tells me it's not a good idea, but I can't put my finger on a reason.

Comment: I'd certainly be interested if you figure it out, but so far I haven't found any. It's nice because the only sort position you need to update is on the item that you are moving. The real data type in SQL server is 4 bytes, just like an int and works for this purpose. The only disadvantage I see is that your sort orders aren't really human-readable, but once you have your sorted values you can easily use ROW_NUMBER() or something to get a UI-friendly order.

Comment: @AndyM Will you really? I would like to see a case where this occurs. Based on how I've seen the algorithm behave I think you may be able to get into this state by repeatedly cycling the order of two items many, many times, but I've never encountered that scenario in practice.

Comment: You'd probably get the number of bits a float has as the number of times you could reorder the same pair of items before you couldn't find a gap anymore - as you say unlikely but possible in a system running for years. If you are worried about this, you could periodically run an update query with RANK to get the rank order and swap the float values in the table with the RANK values.

Comment: @JohnBledsoe For whatever it's worth, I actually have seen this happen in a live system. We had a similar floating point sort order for XBRL tags which are used identify the meaning of numbers in a financial report. I don't recall particularly why the order was critical, but we had some users swapping the order of these elements so that they could view the result. After about 12 swaps, they just couldn't alter the order anymore, for exactly the reason spelled out here. Our solution was just to test for this condition, and if needed, reset the sort order values for every element: 1.0, 2.0, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @NextItem int

SET @NextItem =    (SELECT 
       COUNT(*) + 1 AS NewSortOrder
    FROM 
       MyTable 
    WHERE 
       AnswerRowID=@AnswerRowID 
    ORDER BY 
       SortOrder ASC)


   --now you can use @NextItem
   INSERT INTO AnswerRow(SortOrder, IsDeleted) VALUES(@NextItem, 0)
```

Or you can simply use the current order:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 (ISNULL(SortOrder, 0) + 1) as NewSortOrder FROM AnswerRow WHERE AnswerRowID=@AnswerRowID ORDER BY SortOrder DESC
```

You might want to check if this returns a NULL in case no records exist, check `IsNULL` in BOL.

Either way the point is you want to get the current number, add one to it, and then use that value to do your insert.

Comment: My objective is to have the SortOrder automatically be populated with an incremented value whenever an item is inserted. Sorry if I wasn't clear.